# How to run a cygwin executable with Windows TaskScheduler without opening a terminal?

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin, task-scheduler

Using Windows XP Task Scheduler, I've scheduled the execution of a cygwin program (C:\cygwin\bin\svn.exe update). It is working fine, but when it executes, a terminal window titled svchost.exe opens. It is very annoying.

Is it possible to execute the job without opening this window? At least it would be nice to have it run minimized.

Note: I can't add the cygwin cron service to the machine because I don't have admin permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin's run.exe is intended for this job. See `man run`.

Comment: great! Here is my working command: C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/svn commit -m 'test'. Note that I'm already on the path to be commited

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can run anything without opening the window:

- http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Just run your cygwin command with this .VBS script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Hope this helps.